# How can I remove an active tab in ExtJS when clicking on a delete button?

Tags: extjs

How to remove added tab?
I want to remove the active tab on click on delete.

```
var tabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    items: [{
        // id:0
        title:'tab1',
        html:'text to tab1'
    },{
        // id:2
        title:'tab2',
        html:'text to tab2'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
    text:'add',
    style:{backgroundColor: 'green'},
    handler: function(){
        var tab = tabs.add({
            // id: tabs.items[1].id + 1,
            title: 'tab' +  (tabs.items.length + 1),
            html: 'new tab ' + (tabs.items.length + 1)
        });
        tabs.setActiveTab(tab);
    },
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text:'del',
    style:{backgroundColor:'red'},
    handler: function(){
        // ...  
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
})
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVy0N.png)

As I see the solution:
I need to dynamically assign an id to each tab and then use a loop in the event handler.
If so, how to implement?

Comment: Try `tabs.remove(tabs.getActiveTab())`.

Comment: Everything turned out to be even easier than I thought, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Ext JS can remove a tab automatically if you save it's value when creating. Like `const tab = tabs.add({...})` and then `tabs.remove(tab`. It looks up for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the active Tab by tabPanel.getActiveTab(), and then you can remove it from the tabPanel. tabPanel.remove(activeTab).

I hope this fiddle will help you https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3o0f